# what is the significance of RawComparator and at what scenarios we use this

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is ***RawComparator*** and its significance?

Is it mandatory to use RawComparator for every mapreduce program?

Answer (score 1):

**A  RawComparator directly operates on byte representations of objects**

***it is not mandatory to use it in every map reduce program***

MapReduce is fundamentally a batch processing system, and is not
suitable for interactive analysis. You can’t run a query and get results back in a few seconds or less. Queries typically take minutes or more, so it’s best for offline use, where there is n’t a human sitting in the processing loop waiting for results.

If you still want to optimize time taken by Map Reduce Job, then you have to use RawComparator.

***Use of RawComparator:***

Intermediate key value pairs have been passed from Mapper to Reducer. before these values reach Reducer from Mapper, shuffle and sorting steps will be performed.

Sorting is improved because the RawComparator will compare the keys by byte. If we did not use RawComparator, the intermediary keys would have to be completely de-serialized to perform a comparison.

**Example:**

```
public class IndexPairComparator extends WritableComparator {
    protected IndexPairComparator() {
        super(IndexPair.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
        int i1 = readInt(b1, s1);
        int i2 = readInt(b2, s2);

        int comp = (i1 < i2) ? -1 : (i1 == i2) ? 0 : 1;
        if(0 != comp)
            return comp;

        int j1 = readInt(b1, s1+4);
        int j2 = readInt(b2, s2+4);
        comp = (j1 < j2) ? -1 : (j1 == j2) ? 0 : 1;

        return comp;
    }
}
```

In above example, we did not directly implement RawComparator. Instead we extended WritableComparator, which internally implements RawComparator.

Refer to this [RawComparator](https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/implementing-rawcomparator-will-speed-up-your-hadoop-mapreduce-mr-jobs-2/) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks Sunrise for your reply. You have explained in a simple and undestandable way.

Comment: If it exactly answer your queries, accept the answer.

Comment: But why not deserialize the byte stream? You will need the deserialized objects in reduce task anyway, so why not deserialize earlier at sorting phase?

Comment: Sorting does not require de-serialization ok keys if you use Raw Comparator. Sorting will be fast. Transferring Mapper output to Reducer is different thing, which happens anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering to an old question.

Here is another example of writing a RawComparator for a WritableComparable

```
public class CompositeWritable2 implements WritableComparable<CompositeWritable2> {

  private Text textData1;
  private LongWritable longData;
  private Text textData2;

  static {
    WritableComparator.define(CompositeWritable2.class, new Comparator());
  }

  /**
   * Empty constructor
   */
  public CompositeWritable2() {
    textData1 = new Text();
    longData = new LongWritable();
    textData2 = new Text();
  }

  /**
   * Comparator
   * 
   * @author CuriousCat
   */
  public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {

    private static final Text.Comparator TEXT_COMPARATOR = new Text.Comparator();
    private static final LongWritable.Comparator LONG_COMPARATOR = new LongWritable.Comparator();

    public Comparator() {
      super(CompositeWritable2.class);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator#compare(byte[], int, int, byte[], int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
      int cmp;

      try {
        // Find the length of the first text property
        int textData11Len = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
        int textData12Len = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2);

        // Compare the first text data as bytes
        cmp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, textData11Len, b2, s2, textData12Len);
        if (cmp != 0) {
          return cmp;
        }

        // Read and compare the next 8 bytes starting from the length of first text property.
        // The reason for hard coding 8 is, because the second property is long.
        cmp = LONG_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, textData11Len, 8, b2, textData12Len, 8);
        if (cmp != 0) {
          return cmp;
        }

        // Move the index to the end of the second long property
        textData11Len += 8;
        textData12Len += 8;

        // Find the length of the second text property
        int textData21Len = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[textData11Len]) + readVInt(b1, textData11Len);
        int textData22Len = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[textData12Len]) + readVInt(b2, textData12Len);

        // Compare the second text data as bytes
        return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, textData11Len, textData21Len, b2, textData12Len, textData22Len);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed in CompositeWritable's RawComparator!", ex);
      }
    }

  }

  /**
   * @return the textData1
   */
  public Text getTextData1() {
    return textData1;
  }

  /**
   * @return the longData
   */
  public LongWritable getLongData() {
    return longData;
  }

  /**
   * @return the textData2
   */
  public Text getTextData2() {
    return textData2;
  }

  /**
   * Setter method
   */
  public void set(Text textData1, LongWritable longData, Text textData2) {
    this.textData1 = textData1;
    this.longData = longData;
    this.textData2 = textData2;
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable#write(java.io.DataOutput)
   */
  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    textData1.write(out);
    longData.write(out);
    textData2.write(out);
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable#readFields(java.io.DataInput)
   */
  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    textData1.readFields(in);
    longData.readFields(in);
    textData2.readFields(in);
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
   */
  @Override
  public int compareTo(CompositeWritable2 o) {    
    int cmp = textData1.compareTo(o.getTextData1());
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }

    cmp = longData.compareTo(o.getLongData());
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }

    return textData2.compareTo(o.getTextData2());
  }

}
```